# Aside from level recommendations, when should I start the DLC?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I'm currently replaying Witcher 3. I've done one playthrough before, but haven't played either of the expansion packs before. I was wondering just how 'absolute' the recommendations are (level 30+ each) . Right now I've confirmed Ciri is in neither of the 3 areas and am at level 20+

I've read that the expansion packs give you certain bonuses, like Gwent cards and mutagens or something, so I'd like to get the most out of those. I also wouldn't mind experiencing something fresh and new, rather than most quests I've already been through once.

So, my question is at what point in the story or at what level should I start which DLC? Spoilers for the main story  are fine, but please don't mention anything of HoS or BaW.

Comment: What exactly are you asking?  Are you asking if its possible to do the DLC at a lower level than recommended or are you asking if it would be a good idea?

Comment: The latter, if it's a good idea to start early and if so, how early exactly. I'm pretty sure I can start the whole thing whenever, but I don't want my every foe to be a red skull

Comment: It might be a good idea to edit your question with what you've got in the comment.  Asking "Will the foes scale down to my level?" is a better question.  As is, your question is somewhat broad and opinion based

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the required levels are fairly accurate. Especially for Blood and Wine you will run in to a lot of high level adversaries immediately even before you get to the new area.

I have recently got to this level playing at Death March difficultly. I started Blood and Wine while the main quest 'Final Preparations' was active and I was at around level 34.

If you play much of Blood and Wine you will end up very over leveled for the main story.

Since Hearts of Stone just extends the area of the Velen/Novigrad map you can reach the main merchant and craftsman there without necessarily engaging with high level adversaries. However they won't sell you the really good stuff until you have done some quests. The runewright also requires you to spend quite a lot of crowns (5000 for just the first level). You can buy some Gwent cards and good saddlebags from the merchant, and win a good saddle in a race.

Comment: I'm fine with becoming overleveled for the main quest, especially for the grande finale. I would like to do HoS as early as possible though, without running into a bunch of red skull enemies and making my own life a pain.

Comment: Added something about Hearts of Stone